# Ionic 2 new grid system not align button size as like responsive-sm

Tags: grid, ionic2

I am using the new Ionic 2 [grid system](http://blog.ionic.io/build-awesome-desktop-apps-with-ionics-new-responsive-grid/). I need help with the button size using the grid system with the `col-sm` attribute. When I used `responsive-sm` with rows, the buttons inside the rows arranged the width automatically. How can achieve this with new grid system?

New Code:

```
<ion-row col-sm>
    <button ion-button icon-left>
       <ion-icon name="cloud-upload"></ion-icon> Upload files  Firebase
    </button>

    <button ion-button icon-left color="danger">
        <ion-icon name="remove-circle"></ion-icon> Clear files
    </button>       
</ion-row>
```

Old Code with `responsive-sm`:

```
<ion-row responsive-sm>     
    <button ion-button icon-left>
        <ion-icon name="cloud-upload"></ion-icon> Upload files to Firebase
    </button>

    <button ion-button icon-left color="danger" >
        <ion-icon name="remove-circle"></ion-icon> Clear files
    </button>           
</ion-row>
```

Sample:
[image: sample]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly the `ion-row` should not contain the `col-sm` attribute. The `ion-row` clearly defines the rowed element and not the sizing *per se'*. The responsive attributes should be placed in the `ion-col` in order to clearly define the width steps based on the window size. `ion-rows` should contain `top`, `center` and `bottom`.

The `ion-buttons` should either contain the responsive attribute **or** the buttons should be wrapped in an `ion-col`.

The 2 important attributes to add are the `col-12` and `col-sm` like so

```
<button ion-button col-12 col-sm> Upload files Firebase </ion-col>
```

**col-12**

This attribute specifically defines how many columns ( out of 12 to take up ) 12 being a full length of the window.

**col-sm**
This is the breakpoint used in conjunction with the `col-12`.

> This tells it to take up 12 columns up to the small breakpoint and then change to equal width columns.

This is all based on the new grid system which has official documentation which you [can view for more information](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/grid/Grid/).

You might want to specifically look at [auto layout columns](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/grid/Grid/#auto-layout-columns) in the new grid system for what you would like to achieve.